# Why does CommonMark consider this 7 space indent a code block?

Tags: commonmark

I'm storing some notes with CommonMark and I noticed that this snippet seems to render differently on SO (*echo* is indented **7** spaces).

```
1. Print Windows folder path

       echo %windir%
```

Here it is interpreted as a code block on http://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/:

[image]

And here it is on Stack Overflow:

[image]

If I indent *echo* by **8** spaces instead, it will now show as a code block on Stack Overflow:

[image]

But on http://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/ it now has a leading space (I've selected it to show):

[image]

Is this because SO isn't actually using the full CommonMark spec (yet?)?

Or is there a CommonMark setting to make it render the way SO does?

This is a little annoying because many of my notes are indeed text that could find their way into a question or answer somewhere on Stack Exchange. So I'm just hoping to figure out what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was answered by @balpha in this June 2015 post:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258587/879

> #### List items
>
> Currently, this will create a list item with two paragraphs:
>
> ```
> 1. This is the first paragraph
>
>  And this is the second one.
> ```
>
> With CommonMark (and even [in a significant number of other Markdown
>   implementations](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=-+foo%0A%0A+bar)),
>   the "second one" will not be part of the list item, but a stand-alone
>   paragraph after the list. To make it part of the list item, you have
>   to indent it to the same margin as the first paragraph like this:
>
> ```
> 1. This is the first paragraph
>
>    And this is the second one.
> ```

I was confused by what seemed like a somewhat arbitrary "7 spaces" but now I realize it's in fact 3 spaces to bring it under alignment with the list item, and then the standard 4 spaces which identifies it as a code block.

Confirmed by this little test:

[image]

This actually makes good sense to me, I think I like it.

So that answers that, I guess SE still uses its own variant that doesn't involve this type of alignment.